# Задержка более чем на int32 миллисекунд C#

Tags: c#

Задался вопросом...
Возможно ли создать задержку в C# (Task.Delay()) на число, большее чем INT32 миллисекунд, а допустим на 1000 часов (1000 * 1000 * 60 * 60 мсек)?

Comment: В чём трудность проверить?

Comment: `await Task.Delay(-1)` или `await Task.Delay(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan)` - самое долгое, что можно придумать. А зачем вам так долго?

Comment: Но ведь await Task.Delay(-1) это бесконечная задержка?

Comment: @Caesium1337 по сути - нет.

Comment: Имхо, тут либо таймер нужен, либо планировщик задач.

Comment: 1000 часов - это больше 40 дней. Ваше приложение никогда не выключается? А если компьютер погрузить в сон - после пробуждения задержка должна продолжать действовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение достаточно простое, я бы сказал, даже вот оно, на поверхности.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    await Task.Delay(1000 * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая мысль!